# Android custom listview adapter and numberpicker dialogfragment

Tags: android, listview, numberpicker

I´m trying to create my first Android app, but I can´t do what I want. 
My idea is to create a simple score counter. I have an activity with a listview. Each item of the listview has a TextView with a name, two buttons for adding and subtracting, and a TextView for the score.

My idea was to show a custum numberpicker when the user clicks on the score, to select a number to increase a decrease. The custom numberpicker has an interface to use callback method to get the number selected.

In the activity class, I have a custom adapter for the listview, and a viewholder class to improve the functionality. I have several doubts/problems:

1) When can I define the listeners for the buttons/textviews? Currently I have the listeners in the viewholder, but i'm not sure if it is the better solution, maybe it's better to define them in the adapter, or even create an onitemclicklistener for the listview.

2) Can I implement the method defined in the numberpicker dialog interface inside the adapter or viewholder class? I have tried it but I get a cast exception because the inner class isn't an activity...

3) If I implement the interface method in the activity (outer) class, I´m not able to modify the desired textview that invoked the numberpicker...

My two main problems are where and how to define the listener for each view in the listview rows and how to get the number of the numberpicker dialog and continue with the execution...

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) you define the onClick listeners in the adapter.

2)post your code.

3)post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a listener in a view inside an adapter, the listener should be declared in the adapter and a new listener instance should be created for each view.

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    private CustomListener listener;
    private Button incrementBtn;
}
```

Now in the `getView()` method:

```
holder.listener = new CustomListener(position);
holder.incrementBtn.setOnClickListener(holder.listener);
```

Now define an inherited class to implement the `onClick()` method:

```
private class CustomListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int position;

    protected CustomListener(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //increment score here
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Once the `onClick()` method finishes, the view with update via `notifyDataSetChanged()` with the new score.
To use the number picker dialog, it's the same pattern just with a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` defined in the viewholder.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, sorry...

```
package com.example.cdp.mispartidas;

imports...

public class Tanteo extends ActionBarActivity {

private String identificador;
private Partida partida;
private Backup backup;
private int indice;
private static Context context;

ListView listviewjugadores;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tanteo);

    // Parametros
    listviewjugadores = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jugadorestanteo);

    Tanteo.context = getApplicationContext();

    Log.i("MILOG", "Obtenemos el backup");
    backup = Backup.getMiBackup(getApplicationContext());

    // Obtenemos el numero de jugadores
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    identificador = bundle.getString("idpartida");

    Log.i("MILOG", "El identificador de la partida es " + identificador);


    // Buscamos la partida
    indice = backup.getPartida(identificador);
    if (indice >= 0) {
        partida = backup.getBackup().get(indice);
        // Establecemos el adaptador
        Log.i("MILOG", "Establecemos el adaptador");
        AdaptadorTanteo adaptador = new AdaptadorTanteo(this, getTaskId(), partida.getJugadores());
        listviewjugadores.setAdapter(adaptador);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se ha encontrado la partida " + identificador, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tanteo, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    int numjugadores;

    switch(id){
        // Anadimos un nuevo jugador a la partida
        case R.id.addjugador:
            numjugadores = listviewjugadores.getAdapter().getCount();
            Jugador player = new Jugador();
            // Ponemos un nombre por defecto
            player.setNombre("Jugador" + String.valueOf(numjugadores + 1));
            player.setNumerojugador(numjugadores + 1);
            // Anadimos la puntuacion
            player.setPuntuacion(0);
            // Anadimos el jugador a la lista
            partida.addJugador(player);
            // Actualizamos el backup
            backup.getBackup().set(indice, partida);
            // Almacenamos
            Log.i("MILOG", "Guardamos el backup");
            backup.guardarBackup();
            // Si todo ha ido bien, acutalizamos la lista de jugadores
            ((AdaptadorTanteo) listviewjugadores.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

        case R.id.partidasguardadas:
            // Llamamos al intent de nuestras partidas guardadas
            Intent intenthistorial = new Intent(this, Historial.class);
            startActivity(intenthistorial);
            break;

        case R.id.reiniciarpartida:
            // Ponemos todos los marcadores a 0
            // Recorremos nuestra partida
            numjugadores = partida.getJugadores().size();
            // recorremos y reiniciamos
            for(int i = 0; i < numjugadores; i++){
                partida.getJugadores().get(i).setPuntuacion(0);
            }
            // Actualizamos el backup
            backup.getBackup().set(indice, partida);
            // Almacenamos
            Log.i("MILOG", "Guardamos el backup");
            backup.guardarBackup();
            // Si todo ha ido bien, acutalizamos la lista de jugadores
            ((AdaptadorTanteo) listviewjugadores.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

        case R.id.action_settings:
            break;
        default:
            return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// Adaptador para el layout del listview
public class AdaptadorTanteo extends ArrayAdapter<Jugador> {

    Activity context;
    List<Jugador> jugadores;
    ViewHolder holder;

    AdaptadorTanteo(Activity context, int textViewResourceId, List<Jugador> listajugadores) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, listajugadores);
        this.context = context;
        this.jugadores = listajugadores;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View item = convertView;

        // Optimizamos el rendimiento de nuestra lista
        // Si la vista no existe, la creamos
        if (item == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tanteo_jugador, null);

            // Declaramos el holder pasandole nuestras vistas
            TextView nombre = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.nombrejugador);
            TextView puntuacion = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.puntos);
            ImageButton mas = (ImageButton) item.findViewById(R.id.sumar);
            ImageButton menos = (ImageButton) item.findViewById(R.id.restar);

            holder = new ViewHolder(nombre, puntuacion, mas, menos);

            // Establecemos el tag
            item.setTag(holder);
        }
        // Si la vista existe, la reusamos
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();
        }

        // Guardamos la posicion en el holder para usarlo en los listener
        holder.botonmas.setTag(position);
        holder.botonmenos.setTag(position);
        holder.puntos.setTag(position);

        // Establecemos el nombre por defecto
        holder.nombrejugador.setText(jugadores.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.puntos.setText(String.valueOf(jugadores.get(position).getPuntuacion()));

        return (item);
    }
}


class ViewHolder implements NumeroTanteoDialogFragment.NumberTanteoDialogListener{

    TextView nombrejugador;
    TextView puntos;
    ImageButton botonmas;
    ImageButton botonmenos;
    int position;

    public ViewHolder(TextView nombre, TextView puntuacion, ImageButton mas, ImageButton menos) {

        nombrejugador = nombre;
        puntos = puntuacion;
        botonmas = mas;
        botonmenos = menos;

        // Definimos los listener
        nombrejugador.setOnClickListener(miListenerLocal);
        puntos.setOnClickListener(miListenerLocal);
        botonmas.setOnClickListener(miListenerLocal);
        botonmenos.setOnClickListener(miListenerLocal);

    }

    // Creamos aqui los listener
    // Asi tenemos acceso al resto de vistas dentro de la fila
    private View.OnClickListener miListenerLocal = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            position = (Integer) v.getTag();

            // Comprobamos la vista que lo esta invocando
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.nombrejugador:

                    break;

                case R.id.puntos:
                    try {
                        // Decrementamos el tanteo
                        Log.i("MILOG", "Modificamos el tanteo");
                        // Lanzamos el dialog
                        NumeroTanteoDialogFragment fragmento = new NumeroTanteoDialogFragment();
                        Bundle bundles = new Bundle();
                        bundles.putString("titulo", getString(R.string.sumar_puntos));
                        fragmento.setArguments(bundles);
                        Log.i("MILOG", "Mostramos el dialog para elegir el numero que queremos modificar");
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
                        fragmento.show(fragmentManager, "Dialogo_jugadores");

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(Tanteo.context, "Se produjo un error al modificar el tanteo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;

                case R.id.sumar:
                    try {
                        Log.i("MILOG", "Sumamos uno");
                        // Incrementamos el tanteo
                        int tantos = Integer.parseInt(puntos.getText().toString()) + 1;
                        puntos.setText(String.valueOf(tantos));
                        // Actualizamos el backup
                        partida.getJugadores().get(position).setPuntuacion(tantos);
                        // Actualizamos el backup
                        backup.getBackup().set(indice, partida);
                        // Almacenamos
                        Log.i("MILOG", "Guardamos el backup");
                        backup.guardarBackup();

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(Tanteo.context, "Se produjo un error al incrementar el tanteo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;

                case R.id.restar:
                    try {
                        // Decrementamos el tanteo
                        Log.i("MILOG", "Restamos uno");
                        int tantos = Integer.parseInt(puntos.getText().toString()) - 1;
                        puntos.setText(String.valueOf(puntos));
                        // Actualizamos el backup
                        partida.getJugadores().get(position).setPuntuacion(tantos);
                        // Actualizamos el backup
                        backup.getBackup().set(indice, partida);
                        // Almacenamos
                        Log.i("MILOG", "Guardamos el backup");
                        backup.guardarBackup();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(Tanteo.context, "Se produjo un error al decrementar el tanteo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
    };

    // Sobreescribimos el metodo del dialogo para elegir el numero
    @Override
    public void onNumberSelected(int number) {

        Log.i("MILOG", "Actualizamos los puntos con el dialog");
        int puntuacion = Integer.parseInt(puntos.getText().toString()) + number;
        // Modificamos los puntos
        puntos.setText(String.valueOf(puntuacion));

        // Actualizamos el backup
        partida.getJugadores().get(position).setPuntuacion(puntuacion);
        // Actualizamos el backup
        backup.getBackup().set(indice, partida);
        // Almacenamos
        Log.i("MILOG", "Guardamos el backup");
        backup.guardarBackup();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help,

I´ve solved it using your indications. I´ve defined the listeners as you told me. One of my problems was that I was updating the viewholder object in two different places. I have changed it, and also update the view with notifyDataSetChanged().

The solution for the numberpicker was to implement the callback method in the main activity, and pass the position of the listview as param to change the correct item.

Best regards.